# UIWebView in UIScrollView,UIScrollView how to get Tap Event

Tags: events, uiwebview, uiscrollview, tap

now,i have a UIWebview inside a uiscrollview,i want to detect single tap on uiscrollview,but i have no idea to achieve it!it's so boring!

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest using the MGBox2 controls for your scrollview https://github.com/sobri909/MGBox2. They have an excellent wrapper for a scrollview which exposes tap events easily for the scrollview and the contents thereof.

You would place your UIWebview in an MGBox and add the MGBox to your MGScrollView.

It would then work like this:

```
myScrollView.onTap =^{[self doThisOnTap];};
```

Comment: No need to have the intermediate `MGBox`. Can just add the `UIWebView` directly to the `MGScrollView`. Although putting it inside an `MGBox` will allow you to use `MGLayoutBox` positioning features (margins, padding, etc).